# Разворот односвязного списка - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, односвязный-список

Здравствуйте, уважаемые форумчане. Задачка состоит в том, чтобы проверить "правильность" скобок в строке str.
Задачу нужно решить через односвязный список, я занес в список 1 открывающиеся скобки, а в список 2 закрывающиеся. Вопрос как мне развернуть список 2, чтобы сравнить его с первым списком. Т.е. сейчас при выводе

---

(
[
{

---

}
]
)

---

Или можете предложить другую идею решения (может более рациональную).

```js
var list = function (e) 
{
    var self = this;
    var first, last, head;
 
    self.insert = function (value) {
        var node = new Node(value);
        if (first == null) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            var head = first;
            while (head.next != null) {
                head = head.next;
            }
            head.next = node;
            last = head.next;
        }
    }
    self.show = function () {
        var head = first;
        while (head != null) {
            console.log(head.value);
            head = head.next;
        }
    }
    var Node = function (value) {
        this.value = value;
        var next = {};
    }
    return self;
};
 
var list_1 = new list();
var list_2 = new list();
var str = "(Я [ хочу {программировать} на ] JavaScript)";
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
    if(str[i].indexOf('(') + 1 > 0 || str[i].indexOf('[') + 1 > 0 || str[i].indexOf('{') + 1 > 0)
        list_1.insert(str[i]);
    else if(str[i].indexOf(')') + 1 > 0 || str[i].indexOf(']') + 1 > 0 || str[i].indexOf('}') + 1 > 0)
        list_2.insert(str[i]);
console.log("____________________________");
list_1.show();
console.log("____________________________");
list_2.show();
console.log("____________________________");
```

Comment: я не понял вопроса

Comment: Просто ложите скобки в стэк и извлекаете при прохождении обратной скобки. Я не вижу что в вашем коде используется стэк.

Comment: Два списка это точно лишнее и неправильное